# Fit content sections to scrolling page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with content on my page while scrolling. What I mean:
The website has been divided into 5 different sections. When scrolling (I will move the roll, e.g. 6 times), I expect the appearance of section-1, in such a way that the top of the section-1 container is at the top of the entire page. When I move the roller e.g. 4 times I should see the top of the container section-2 at the top of the entire page etc...

Maybe picture will show what I expect.
[image]

Comment: I add, all section has dynamically height (depend of text inside)

Comment: I suppose you're looking for the `scroll-snap` property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Terry suggested, the [CSS `scroll-snap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts) property is what you want.

```css
.scroller {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.scroller section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<article class="scroller">
  <section style="height: 150%; background: orange">
    <h2>Section one</h2>
  </section>
  <section style="height: 90%; background: lightblue">
    <h2>Section two</h2>
  </section>
  <section style="height: 200%; background: lightgreen">
    <h2>Section three</h2>
  </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Snaps looks good, but disallow me on to read content below section.

```html
<article class="scroller">
  <section style="height: 150%; background: orange">
    <h2>Section one</h2>
  </section>
  <p>
    long content section
  </p>
  <section style="height: 90%; background: lightblue">
    <h2>Section two</h2>
  </section>
  <p>
    long content section
  </p>
  <section style="height: 200%; background: lightgreen">
    <h2>Section three</h2>
  </section>
  <p>
    long content section
  </p>
</article>
```

I cannot scroll to `<p>long content section</p>`.

PS:

Ok I soloved problem, I wanted that: `scroll-snap-type: y proximity;`